# Would there be a way of making this loop run faster?

Tags: python, python-re, stemming

```
a = []

for i in range(0, len(content)):
    
    norm = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', content['text'][i]).lower()
    norm = norm.split()
    norm = [PorterStemmer().stem(word) for word in norm if not word in 
     stopwords.words('english')]
    
    norm = ' '.join(norm)
    a.append(norm)
```

Comment: You can compile the regexp, store `stopwords.words('english')` in a variable to not access everytime in the list comprehension, and maybe use [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/)

Comment: The last 3 lines can all be joined into one line (and dont create the list at all) which would probably be "faster" but then without knowing much about the context its hard to say. I.e can the `PorterStemmer`  instance be created and reused?

Comment: see [codereview.se] but i'm not sure if in its current state this would be on topic there

Comment: If `i` is the current element index in `content`, why are you using it to index into `content['text']`?

Comment: If `stopwords.words()` is a function, calling it repeatedly seems very wasteful.  Try calling it _once_ and saving the result (preferably in a set).